# Add active state to first item in jCarousel Lite

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, jcarousellite

When I initialize jCarousel Lite I want to be able to add a 'class="active"' state to my first element in the list. How would I approach this without modifying the plugin?

Current setup -

```
$('#viewport').jCarouselLite({
    speed: 500,
    visible: 3,
    scroll: 1,
    start: 0, // Just for testing purposes
    circular: true,
    btnNext: '#next',
    btnPrev: '#previous',
    beforeStart: function(a) {
        $(a[0]).animate({opacity: .5}, 250).toggleClass('active');
    },
    afterEnd: function(a) {
        $(a[0]).animate({opacity: 1}, 500).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the initialization of your jCarouselLite,

do the following

```
$('#viewport ul li:first').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks, that will have to do until there's a built in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if I'm way off track. Are you not able to add this class prior to the initialisation of jCarouselLite?

Add the code in between the comment tags to the jCarousel source.

```
div.css(sizeCss, divSize+"px");                     // Width of the DIV. length of visible images

/* add this */

    if(o.atStart){
        o.atStart.call(this, vis());
    }else{
        //not set
    }

/**/

    if(o.btnPrev)
        $(o.btnPrev).click(function() {
            return go(curr-o.scroll);
        });
```

Then pass in an additional parameter to the jCarousel initialisation:

```
$('#viewport').jCarouselLite({
    speed: 500,
    visible: 3,
    scroll: 1,
    start: 0, // Just for testing purposes
    circular: true,
    btnNext: '#next',
    btnPrev: '#previous',
    beforeStart: function(a) {
        $(a[0]).animate({opacity: .5}, 250).toggleClass('active');
    },
    afterEnd: function(a) {
        $(a[0]).animate({opacity: 1}, 500).toggleClass('active');
    },
    atStart: function(a){
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I did explain it a bit misleading. What I'm looking for is a callback (an "atStart" function, sort of) inside the jCarousel Lite options.

Comment: Unfortunately one doesn't exist, however you can easily add one within the source code. I know you didn't want to modify the plugin, however this is a minor change and one that can most likely be migrated across future releases.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using a simple addClass like the example Shawn provided above.

Comment: No probs, whatever is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeStart: function(a) { 
     $(a[0]).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

}

// Finished with only this little script